# Data Repeater items Does Not Displayed on another machine

Tags: c#-4.0, datarepeater

I have set the **data source of Data Repeater in C# Windows Application** to a collection of **Images**

,every thing is good on my machine and the **Images Displayed successfully** ,but when I try to Run my

Windows Application on ***another machine*** **- The Images Are Not Displayed -**

**How can i fix this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by installing this tool on the client machine **VisualBasicPowerPacks3Setup.exe** and it works good